# Converting from std::string to "MyShmString" when sharing memory with boost::interprocess

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, interprocess

I am following this [boost::interprocess guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained.where_allocate) and this [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980716/create-a-shared-memory-vector-of-strings/13041949) in order to share std::string variables among different processes. Specifically, I have a function which recieves a std::string that should be shared among other processes:

```
void registerFailedTests(std::string failed_test_name) {

    boost::interprocess::permissions perm;
    perm.set_unrestricted();

    boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove(unit_tests_constants::shm_failed_tests_list.c_str());
    boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory managed_shm_failed_tests_list(boost::interprocess::open_or_create, unit_tests_constants::shm_failed_tests_list.c_str(), 10240, 0, perm);

    typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<char, boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> CharAllocator;
    typedef boost::interprocess::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CharAllocator> myShmString;

    CharAllocator charallocator(managed_shm_failed_tests_list.get_segment_manager());

    myShmString mystring(charallocator);
}
```

The problem is that the parameter failed_test_name is a std::string, and I cannot turn it into a myShmString type in order to allocate it in shared memory.

How could I achieve this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use any constructor that copies from an input sequence:

```
myShmString mystring(failed_test_name.begin(), failed_test_name.end(), charallocator);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I need! I had a look previously to basic_string constructors, but I couldn't bound that information with my problem. I really thank you!

Comment: Cheers!  Welcome to SO. Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work